# VueJS | How to get access to Router Parameter in my Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I tried to get access to my parameter **:id** in my **Entry** component. I tried it with props but it doesn't work. Any idea? Can't find anything.

```
export default new Router({
    routes: [{
        path: '/entry/:id',
        name: 'Entry',
        component: Entry
    }]
})
```

Thank you

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While soju's answer is correct, I tend to use the method in which the docs refer to as 'decoupling the router using props'.

This can be accomplished by add the props: true option to your route and defining a property in your component.

So in your Route you would have:

```
export default new Router({
     routes: [{
          path: '/entry/:id',
          name: 'Entry',
          component: Entry,
          props: true
     }]
})
```

Then in your component you add a prop:

```
Vue.component('Entry', {
       template: '<div>ID: {{ id}}</div>',
       props:['id']
})
```

This can all be found in the docs:
[Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html)

Answer (score 20):

You should simply use `$route.params.id` or `this.$route.params.id`.

Read more : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

You should consider using props : https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: or, this.$route.params.id

Answer (score 14):

you can use in component

```
this.$route.params.id
```

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer

Answer (score 7):

With in html `<div>{{$route.params.id}}</div>`

With in Script `this.$route.params.id`

Answer (score 4):

```
<template>
    <div>
      <p>{{id}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                id:this.$route.params.id
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer .Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer